# Doubts on 404 because htaccess - What is happening here?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a WP instance, and I see that any time I write a URL that has any string that contains `moz` it errors out with a 404.

I have taken a look at my `.htaccess` looking for `moz` and I see this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moz(.*)
```

Why would that be causing a 404?

The context of this `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/knowledge/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/midphase(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moz(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Stats/(.*)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do the files exist?

Comment: Yes. It does exist.

Comment: If they exist then look in the error log, if there is nothing in the error log then make sure you LogLevel is set to `Info` or more verbose (Apache v2.4 only). If there is still nothing, then the request is still being rewritten somehow and you will probably need to enable logging for mod_rewrite, details here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog

Answer (score -1):

What is happening here is that, all the URLs which contain `/knowledge/` or `/midphase` or `/moz` or `/Stats/` will show a 404. If you don't want that to happen remove these rules. Htaccess works using regular expressions to match.

Read here for more knowledge: [Using .htaccess rewrite rules](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

Comment: This is an overly simplistic view of what the block of rewrite conditions and the `RewriteRule` does. However explaining in full would not fit well at all into a comment.

Comment: However, the OP has already stated that these files _do exist_ and the first condition (ie. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) ensures that the request is only processed by this directive when the file does not exist. So, in this example, those directives should do nothing and the file should simply be served. So, something else must be going on here.